# 17 seconds delay at boot

Tags: boot, mount

my Ubuntu install take extraordinary amount of time to boot. I have a MacBook Air 2014 with Ubuntu 16.04 installed on a USB stick. According to `dmesg` the delay is here:

```
[    3.166478] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    3.167125] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 60063744 512-byte logical blocks: (30.8 GB/28.6 GiB)
[    3.168958] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    3.168962] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[    3.169826] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    3.202890]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 < sdb5 >
[    3.205129] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[    3.548151] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    3.581976] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     APPLE    SD Card Reader   3.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    3.582455] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[    3.583683] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   20.022675] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   20.403096] systemd[1]: systemd 229 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN)
[   20.420092] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: So, Ubuntu is on a USB stick? These can be slow, which may be the cause of the delay. It is not unusual to have such a delay for HDDs too. You'll need an SSD to get rid of it.

Comment: Another command you can try is `systemd-analyze blame` which lists how long each step takes to execute.